# Installing ruby 1.9 on Mac OS X 10.7

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, ruby

I'm trying to install [Kitabu](https://github.com/jstorimer/kitabu) on Mac OS X 10.7.4.

When I tried to use `gem install kitabu --pre` to install kitabu, I got an error

```
ERROR:  Error installing kitabu:
        kitabu requires Ruby version ~> 1.9.
```

And the preinstalled ruby is not version 1.9.

```
ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2011-12-28 patchlevel 357) [universal-darwin11.0]
```

Can I update preinstalled ruby to 1.9? If that's not possible, how can I install ruby 1.9 so that I can run it when gem is executed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No don't update the Apple supplied ruby as that could affect existing ruby scripts and will get overridden in a System Upgrade.

To install ruby see the [Download Ruby page](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/downloads/) from the ruby language website (the main page of which you should have bookmarked)

The two ways that you should consider are

1. Download the RVM. Then edit your .bash_profile to put the bin path
   of the install at the front of your PATH.
2. Use a package manager (e.g. Macports, Fink, Homebrew) and put their
   path at the front of your PATH ( I would use this only if you have C   libraries that you need as well)

Comment: [RVM. RVM. RVM. RVM. RVM. RVM. RVM. RVM.](https://rvm.io/) Period.

Comment: RVM first until you need a binary library that us difficult to get

Answer (score 0):

I just want to throw in here that I much prefer [rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv) to RVM. Using [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) install with:

```
$ brew update
$ brew install rbenv
$ brew install ruby-build
$ brew install rbenv-gemset
```